# Increase in security with increase in size of salt

Tags: hash, passwords, salt

Does increasing or doubling the size of salt result in improved security?

It will require some extra time to brute force the passwords, but any added advantage?

Comment: Should I delete the question or wait for a better answer that will give us a detailed explanation?

Comment: No need to delete. If you think that link answers your question, you can let it be closed as duplicate. If you do not, you can [edit] to clarify how your question differs and what remains unanswered.